# PHP class method call not displaying all errors

Tags: php

```
<?php

class Validator {

public $errors = array(
        'password' => '', 
        'email' => '');

const PASSWORD_MINCHARS = 8;

public function checkEmail($email) {

    if ($this->checkEmpty($email)) {
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $this->errors['email'] = "Please provide a valid email";
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }   
    } else {
        $this->errors['email'] = "Please provide a value for the email";
        return FALSE;
    }
}

public function checkPassword($string) {

    if ($this->checkEmpty($string)) {

        if (strlen($string) < self::PASSWORD_MINCHARS) {
            $this->errors['password'] = "The password should be atleast ".self::PASSWORD_MINCHARS." characters long.";
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }

    } else {
        $this->errors['password'] = "Please provide a value for the password";
        return FALSE; 
    }

}

private function checkEmpty($string) {
    if (!empty($string)) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

public function displayErrors() {
    $output = '';
    foreach ($this->errors as $error) {
        if (!empty($error)) {
            $output .= '<p>'.$error.'</p>';
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

 }

   ?>

   <?php

    require 'Validator.php';


      $validator = new Validator();


        $email = '';
        $password = '';


     if ($validator->checkPassword($password) && $validator->checkEmail($email)) {
echo 'You have entered a valid password and email.';
      } else {
echo $validator->displayErrors();
        }

      ?>
```

The above code comes from two separate files. The one that comes begins with class Validator comes from Validator.php while the one that begins with the require function comes from index.php. So am just wondering why the method call that is $validator->displayErrors() in index.php only displays one error at a time instead of displaying them all at once.

Comment: Does the script run completely? Because if it aborts after the first error, its kinda obvious that it wont show all.

Comment: Just a note on style, you might want to rethink some of your method names.  For example, `if ($this -> checkEmpty ($val))` doesn't really scan.  The checkEmpty() method exists to answer a question, whether or not the given argument is empty. If you named it isEmpty instead the call would be `if ($this -> isEmpty ($val))`, which I think is a bit more readable. Method names should generally state what the method is for rather than what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one error displayed because of your condition:

```
if ($validator->checkPassword($password) && $validator->checkEmail($email))
```

It executes your checkPassword method first, it returns false and so the second condition (which should execute the second validation method) is never checked.

You can avoid this by executing the validation methods first:

```
$validPassword = $validator->checkPassword($password);
$validEmail = $validator->checkEmail($email);

if ($validPassword && $validEmail) {
    echo 'You have entered a valid password and email.';
} else {
    echo $validator->displayErrors();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if ($validator->checkPassword($password) && $validator->checkEmail($email))
```

with

```
if ($validator->checkPassword($password) || $validator->checkEmail($email)) {
```

Comment: I have just tried your solution but it has a issue in that when it checks the first condition for the password and it turns out to be true it doesn't check the second condition of checking the email so in sense accepts a wrong email.